add an unknown column in where clause
I need to filter a column using a WHERE condition but I get this error:
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'GOALS_MIN' in 'where clause'

This is my structure:
+-----------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
| TEAM                  | GOALS | GOALS_MAX | GOALS_MIN |
+-----------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+

and this is my actual query:
SET @TOTAL := (select count(id) from matches);
SELECT
  TEAM,
  sum(RESULT) as GOALS,
  max(RESULT) as GOALS_MAX,
  min(RESULT) as GOALS_MIN
FROM
  (SELECT HOME as TEAM,
    CASE WHEN RESULT_HOME > RESULT_VISIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WIN,
    CASE WHEN RESULT_HOME = RESULT_VISIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as DRAW,
    CASE WHEN RESULT_HOME < RESULT_VISIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as LOSS, RESULT_HOME as RESULT
  FROM matches
  UNION ALL
 SELECT VISIT as TEAM,
    CASE WHEN RESULT_VISIT > RESULT_HOME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WIN,
    CASE WHEN RESULT_VISIT = RESULT_HOME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as DRAW,
    CASE WHEN RESULT_VISIT < RESULT_HOME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as LOSS, RESULT_VISIT as RESULT
  FROM matches
) as t 
WHERE TEAM LIKE '%TEAM1%' OR TEAM LIKE '%TEAM1%' AND GOALS_MIN >= '2'
GROUP BY TEAM
ORDER BY WIN DESC;

How can I filter via column GOALS_MIN using the last AND (GOALS_MIN >= '2')
Thanks in advance.

WHERE is done before GROUP BY and SELECT. You need to use HAVING clause.

that beacuse the GOALS_MIN not exist in table t , and GOALS_MIN value is clac in outer query , try this :
SET @TOTAL := (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM matches);  

SELECT  
  TEAM,  
  SUM(RESULT) AS GOALS,  
  MAX(RESULT) AS GOALS_MAX,  
  MIN(RESULT) AS GOALS_MIN  
FROM  
  (  
    SELECT HOME AS TEAM,  
           RESULT_HOME AS RESULT  
    FROM matches  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT VISIT AS TEAM,  
           RESULT_VISIT AS RESULT  
    FROM matches  
  ) AS t   
WHERE TEAM LIKE '%TEAM1%'  
GROUP BY TEAM  
HAVING MIN(RESULT) >= 2  
ORDER BY WIN DESC;


very thanks! that's it
